# Latency between instructions

Tags: architecture, mips, pipeline

What is the latency between a Add and store instruction in MIPS pipeline . 
Suppose I have the following two instructions.

```
ADD.D F4,F0,F2
S.D   F4,0(R1)
```

It is given in the book that these two have a latency of `2 CC` , but what I think is that it need not be any, if we can bypass the values in the pipeline .
As soon as the value of `F4` is ready in the `3rd CC` , we can forward the value in `F4` to the `S.D` instruction because `R1` has nothing to do with `ADD.D` instruction .

If I am wrong in thinking so , then what is the correct latency ?

Comment: Store requires use of the adder to calculate the offset. In this case it's 0, but in the general case it may not be

Comment: We have a MUX for the 2nd input of the ALU , one input comes from the immediate field of the instruction and the ohter is the value from register which is to be stored , that is F4 in this case even if we forward directly , there should not be any problem because the value of F4 reaches independently to the EX/MEM , without any interference from the immediate value !